# Using pmdarima auto arima with non-time series (integer) index

Tags: pandas, time-series, pmdarima

Is it possible to use pmdarima auto arima with an index that is integer-based (not time series) based?  I'm trying but getting errors.

In short I have the following series:

```
-1094     0.0
-1093     0.0
-1092     0.0
-1091     0.0
-1090     0.0
         ... 
-4       15.0
-3        3.0
-2        2.0
-1        2.0
 0        4.0
Name: total_daily_reg, Length: 1095, dtype: float64
```

When I run this code:

```
from pmdarima import auto_arima

arima_model = auto_arima(train_series, seasonal=True, m=7,error_action='ignore',stepwise=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'end'
```

Insights appreciated.